# Snowflake Compute Capacity

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We use Snowflake on AWS and have some "Daily Jobs" to rebuild our data on daily basis. Some of jobs take ~2+ hours to be built on Large Size Snowflake Warehouse. As about price per [this document](https://www.snowflake.com/blog/how-usage-based-pricing-delivers-a-budget-friendly-cloud-data-warehouse/) I can state that 2 hours of computations on Medium Warehouse = 1 hour computation on Large Warehouse. Should we consider running our stuff on X-Large Warehouse for ~30 mins and are there any engineering/SQL related drawbacks/issues? We want to get our data modelled in less amount of time and for the same amount of money.
Thank you in advance!
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/credits.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way it is supposed to work is that yes, cost doubles but computational power doubles leading to the same cost as it takes half the time

This is not always true for things like data loading where increasing warehouse size does not always mean faster loading (many factors involved in this, file size etc)

If your tasks are ordered correctly and you don't have a situation where you need a previous task to be finished first due to dependency, then I see no reason why you shouldn't do it.

At the very least, you should test one for one of the daily runs

Comment: Yeah, the tasks are ordered correctly. They are just sql+jinja code in most cases targeted towards raw data already loaded into the system, so I am assuming all these things are more SQL dependent. Any advise which DW size we should try?

Comment: All depends on what your target completion time is. You seem to have a pretty good idea of how long it is currently taking so work from there. You might find that upping to the next size actually completes it more than 2x as the WH can do it all in memory and doesn't need to spool to disk.

Comment: Data loading (from remote destinations) is one of the things are is nearly always linear with warehouse size. It is processes like the window functions with limited partitioning or strange JOIN patterns that do not scale well. But as with everything test, test, test, aka try and see.

Comment: Looks like for one job(so far) we've got a more than x2 speed up(2.6 speed up to be explicit). As far as I understand per Dean Flinter's comment we can say that data allocation(RAM/disk) could be something similar as comparing to Spark and MapReduce between each other? Please correct me if I understand it wrong

Comment: @nhply I haven't used either of them so can't say if the comparison is correct. What I meant was that if the data volume/operation exceeds the RAM of the warehouse, it has to then write some of it to disk, which would be slower. As you increase warehouse size you also increase RAM meaning that Snowflake could then do the whole job in memory, without spilling to disk, leading to a performance increase greater than whatever X multiple you increased the warehouse size to

Comment: Ah, alright. Thanks for your help there. Much appreciated